# How to export .trace file to a csv file in macOS sierra

Tags: macos, export-to-csv, instruments, xcode-instruments

I have a .trace file created using the time profiling in the instruments.app
I was trying to convert the trace into a csv file using the `Export Data` option but that was disabled in the instruments app in my macOS Sierra

Is there any other way I can convert the `trace` into a `.csv` file? like via command line or any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

If the Export Data menu item is disabled, it means that particular instrument does not support exporting to a CSV file. Instruments has many instruments. Some of them support exporting to CSV and some of them don't.