# Xcode Instruments - Activity Monitor - cannot export data to CSV

Tags: csv, instruments, xcode-instruments

I am using the Activity Monitor instrument with Xcode to monitor CPU usage on an app.  Is there any way I can export the data to a CSV file?  The Export Data option is greyed out.  Is there any way around this?  If anyone can help I would appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: You could try the Time Profiler instrument and see if it supports exporting to CSV. Otherwise see the following question: [How to export .trace file to a csv file in macOS sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082800/how-to-export-trace-file-to-a-csv-file-in-macos-sierra/46104272#46104272)

Comment: Thanks but the Time Profiler instrument does not support exporting to CSV either.  Thanks for the link but that question is unresolved unfortunately.